# How do we make WPF slider increase by a number different from the tick frequency?

Tags: c#, wpf

In XAML I have:

```
<Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="100" TickPlacement="BottomRight"
    AutoToolTipPlacement="BottomRight"   IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" TickFrequency="10" />
```

With this the slider moves in 10 steps. When I change `IsSnapToTickEnabled` to false, the slider increases  by 1. How do I increase the slider by 2 while keeping the tick frequency to 10?

Comment: Have you tried `SmallChange="2"` as property?

Comment: yeah, I tried but it does not have any effect

Comment: Do you use any code behind, where you could increase the change of the value by 2?

Comment: I have not used any code behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I increase the slider by 2 while keeping the tick frequency to 10?

Handling the `ValueChanged` event should work:

```
private bool _handle = true;
private void val_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    if (_handle)
    {
        _handle = false;
        Slider slider = sender as Slider;
        slider.Value = Math.Round(e.NewValue / 2.0) * 2.0;
        _handle = true;
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="100" TickPlacement="BottomRight" AutoToolTipPlacement="BottomRight"  
        IsSnapToTickEnabled="False"
        ValueChanged="val_ValueChanged"
    SmallChange="2" LargeChange="2"
        TickFrequency="10" />
```